# How to create django view inside tests

Tags: python, django

I have some utility, which consist of middleware, and I need to test it.
I need some view to emulate user request and I'm trying create view inside my test and use it in TestCase. But I don't know how to create it and assign to my test application.

I have some settings for my test django application in `run_tests.py` file:

```py
from django.conf import settings, global_settings

app_name = 'my_app'
conf_kwargs = dict(
    DATABASES={
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': 'test.db',
            'TEST_NAME': 'test.db'
        }
    },
    SITE_ID=1,
    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES=global_settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES + ('my_app.middleware.MyMiddleware',),
    INSTALLED_APPS=(
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.sites',
    )
)

settings.configure(**conf_kwargs)

from django.test.utils import get_runner
runner = get_runner(settings)()
failures = runner.run_tests((app_name,))
```

And then in the `tests.py` file I'm trying:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.test import RequestFactory, TestCase


def active_view(request):
    return HttpResponse('<h1>Test view has responsed<h1>')


class ActiveUsersTest(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.factory = RequestFactory()
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(username='test', email='test@test.com', password='secret')

    def test_view(self):
        request = self.factory.get(active_view)
        request.user = self.user
        response = active_view(request)

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Should I do separate test application for my goals?
This example is running with Django 1.6

Answer (score 0):

When trying to test a view only defined in your tests, the key thing is to `@override_settings(ROOT_URLCONF=__name__)` so that the `urlpatterns` you defined are available to e.g. `reverse`

An example:

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.test.utils import override_settings
from django.urls import path, reverse


def view_for_testing(request):
    # your non-production view
    return HttpResponse(status=200)


urlpatterns = [
    path('/view_for_testing/', view_for_testing, name='view_for_testing')
]


# ensure the test view/urlpattern registered above are usable
@override_settings(ROOT_URLCONF=__name__)
def test_xyz(client):
    response = client.get(reverse('view_for_testing'))
    # your test
```

Note: `client` is a pytest fixture, though the general principle shouldn't rely on pytest.